# jQuery Datatables Server side pagination POST method

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, datatables

I have a working jQuery Datatables implementation in WCF (.NET 4.5) using GET method where I can specify AJAX URL with parameters appended. I'm trying to convert from GET to POST method to overcome the issue with Internet Explorer that is crashing with large data. (Please refer: [jQuery DataTables with Lots of Columns Crashes in IE](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2011/02/16/jquery-datatables-with-lots-of-columns-crashes-in-ie/))

The following code is the datatables initialization.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/Member.svc/GetAllMembersByCategory",
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.ajax( {
            "dataType": 'json', 
            "type": "POST", 
            "processData": true,
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "url": sSource, 
            "data": '{"category":"admin"}', 
            "success": fnCallback
        } );
    }
} );
} );
```

For the method `GetAllMembersByCategory` I need to pass parameter as `{"category":"admin"}`

Now, my question is how do I specify the parameter to the POST method in Datatables initialization above.

**UPDATE**

Modified ajax call, and now it calls the wcf method and that returns data properly. However, the datatable does not load anything but stuck with message "Processing..."

Answer (score 0):

I have not used jQuery datatables before, but if you want to send additional data across a ajax post request the way you do, you could add them as a property/value to aoData..

```
aoData['category'] = 'admin';
```

Cheers

Comment: see update1. Found a way to pass parameters. but datatable is not showing

Comment: How did you check return data. Use something like Fiddler and make sure its exactly matches the expected format